# Bash syntax error when pressing tab to autocomplete

Tags: bash, autocomplete, fedora

I'm getting a strange syntax error in `bash` when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete the rest of a file name. The command I'm trying to execute is `virsh define win10.xml`, but this is what happens (you can see where I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete):

```sh
virsh define wibash: ((: 62 0 0: syntax error in expression (error token is "0 0")
bash: ((: 67 0 0: syntax error in expression (error token is "0 0")
```

This is my `.bashrc`:

```sh
# .bashrc

# Custom parameters
tprompt () {
    local bold=$(tput bold)
    local red=$(tput setaf 1)
    local green=$(tput setaf 2)
    local magenta=$(tput setaf 5)
    local cyan=$(tput setaf 6)
    local plain=$(tput sgr0)
    printf -v PS1 '%s' \
        '\[\033[1;36m\]' \
        '\u\[\033[1;31m\]' \
        '@\[\033[1;32m\]' \
        '\h\[\033[1;35m\]' \
        '\w\[\033[1;31m\]' \
        '\$\[\033[0m\] '
}
tprompt

tput () {
    printf '\\['
    command tput "$@"
    printf '\\]'
}

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

# Source bash aliases
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
. ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# User specific environment
if ! [[ "$PATH" =~ "$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:" ]]
then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
export PATH

# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging feature:
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=

# User specific aliases and functions
if [ -d ~/.bashrc.d ]; then
    for rc in ~/.bashrc.d/*; do
        if [ -f "$rc" ]; then
            . "$rc"
        fi
    done
fi

unset rc

source ~/.local/share/blesh/ble.sh
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/bin/pkgconf:/usr/lib/pkgconfig"
```

I've tried Googling to see if I can find something, but to no avail. Is it something the `.bashrc` which is causing this?

**EDIT:** forgot to mention that I am using [ble.sh](https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh).

Comment: ??? Considedring your `tprompt`function, You're doing 12 useless forks, as each call to `$(tput ..)` implie two forks, all this for populating unused variables!!

Comment: I'm kinda new to Linux so, tbh, I don't know what the first block of code does exactly... I found a tutorial online and I followed it. How should it look?

Comment: there's no arithmetic in this bashrc. The problem could be in ~/.bash_aliases, it could in any file in ~/.bashrc.d, it could be in ble.sh. You'll have to dig deeper.

Comment: Does this mean that it's also possible that it wasn't I who did something wrong?

Comment: It's probably a conflict (or bug) in how your ble.sh package (which does completion) handles the `virsh` completion script. Try disabling or uninstalling ble.sh and see if it still happens (try just commenting `source ... ble.sh` at the bottom of bashrc). If you wanted to, you could backup + remove `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/virsh` (or the equivalent path on Fedora) to disable those completions. Bash will still do file name completion, but you won't get `virsh` specific completions.

Comment: Commenting out `source` in the `.bashrc` sure did the trick, so it is a bug in ble.sh, then. I guess I'll have to notify the dev about it.